# Cómo vincular varias funciones al botón Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen día, estoy buscando la forma de que un botón de tkinter pueda accionar dos funciones que seria poder cambiar de ventana en el frame y cambiar el valor de una variable global, una vez hecho esto, en la ventana que se abrió mostraría por medio de un `Listbox` un `String` que se encuentra en una posición de una lista  global.

lo que pasa es que al probar el código puedo cambiar entre ventanas pero no esta cambiando la variable global para  mostrar el `String` correcto, debería estar  mostrando `"sinopsis"`, tampoco tengo errores en la consola así que no entiendo el porque la función `cambiar()` no esta siendo ejecutada.

Este es el código:

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk

lista=["default","sinopsis"]

variable_global=0

class Inicio(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent )

        #---> BOTON VER
        btnVer1 = tk.Button(self, text="VER", bg = "#F3D306", height = 2, width = 13,command=lambda:[controller.show_frame(InfoPelicula),self.cambiar()] )
        btnVer1.place(x = 365, y = 350)

    def cambiar(self):
        global variable_global
        variable_global = 1
    

class InfoPelicula(tk.Frame):
  
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        lstDescripcion = Listbox(self, height = 13, width = 65)
        lstDescripcion.place(x=542, y=441)
        lstDescripcion.insert(0,lista[variable_global])

        #---> BOTON ATRAS
        btnAtras = tk.Button(self, text="ATRAS", bg = "#F3D306",  height = 2, width = 25, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Inicio))
        btnAtras.place(x = 390, y = 686)
'''
Class Cinema

- clase que se encarga de la creacion de la ventana principal del programa que llama al resto de frames/pantallas.

'''

class Cinema(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        window = tk.Frame(self)
        window.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)
        
        window.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize = 760)
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize = 980)
        
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Inicio, InfoPelicula):
            frame = F(window, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame(Inicio)
        
    def show_frame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()
        self.title("Cinema")
        
            
app = Cinema()
app.maxsize(980,760)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

En Python (Tkinter) si es posible ejecutar y/o vincular varias funciones a la vez en un control como los botones pasándolas a una función anónima mediante la expresión `lambda`.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
def ApplySetting1State():
    ... #Código de la función
 
def ApplySetting2State():
    ... #Código de la función

BtnEjemplo  = ttk.Button(..., text='Aceptar', takefocus=False, command=lambda:[ApplySetting1State(), ApplySetting2State()]
```

Tenga en cuenta que los paréntesis son la razón principal de que la función sea ejecutada cuando se administra con `command` por medio de un botón. Por lo tanto, el uso `lambda` solo es necesario cuando la función tiene sus propios parámetros o necesita ejecutar varias funciones a la vez.